# Troubleshooting on device with Titanium for iPhone

Tags: iphone, titanium, device

On Xcode when you build on device you can troubleshoot the app within the console. How can i do that with Titanium? It's very difficult without troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the `Ti.API.info('whatever')` method to log everything you need and will help in debugging then while you run your app on the device and it is connected to your computer, just open xcode -> go to organizer -> click on your device -> and select console. Every `Ti.API.info()` log you do in your app will show up in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium's SDK (http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk) is Eclipse with the Aptana plug-in. You can do the same debugging you'd do in Eclipse: set break points, step through code, set watch points, ...

To run your app in debug mode, start by setting some break points in your app. To do that right-click on the line number that's on the far left of our line of code and select "Toggle Breakpoint". Next, towards the top of the Project Explorer panel are several icons. One of them is debug. Click on that debug's dropdown menu and select the iphone emulator or ipad emulator. The app will compile for debug and run the emulator you chose. From this point on, everything is like debugging on Eclipse.

Comment: I need to debug on the device because I am using geolocation.

Comment: I don't think there's a Titanium debugger that runs on an actual device. As slash197 suggests you can use logs, or you could use analytics, alert boxes, or create a screen to display the information you need and tweak parameters in your app. Sorry.